# MS SQL join/insert with non unique matching rows via script?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join

I need to to prove the existence of the amount of values from table1 in an MS SQL DB.

The table1 for proving has the following values:

```
MANDT   DOKNR      LFDNR
1       0020999956  
1       0020999958  
1       0020999960  2
1       0020999960  3
1       0020999960  
1       0020999962
```

As you can see there are single rows and then there are special cases, where values are doubled with a running number (means it exists three times in the source), so all 2nd/3rd/further entries do get a increasing number in LFDNR.

The target table2 (where I need to proove for the amount/existance) has two columns with matching data:

```
DataID      Facet
42101976    0020999956
42100240    0020999958
65688960    0020999960
65694287    0020999960
65697507    0020999960
42113401    0020999962
```

I would like to insert the DataID from 2nd table to the first table to have a 'proof', so to see if anything is missing from table2 and keep the table1 as proof.

I tried to uses joins and then I thought about a do while script running all rows down, but my knowledge stops creating scripts for this.

Edit:
Output should be then:

```
MANDT   DOKNR      LFDNR    DataID      
1       0020999956          42101976
1       0020999958          42100240
1       0020999960  2       65688960
1       0020999960  3       65694287
1       0020999960          65697507
1       0020999962          42113401
```

But it could be, for example, that a row in table 2 is missing, so a DataID would be empty then (and show that one is missing).

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to calculated `[LFDNR]` for each row in the second table, then to update the first table. If the `[DataID]` is null after the update, we have a mismatch.

```
DECLARE @table1 TABLE
(
    [MANDT] INT
   ,[DOKNR] VARCHAR(32)
   ,[LFDNR] INT
   ,[DataID] INT
);

DECLARE @table2 TABLE
(
    [DataID] INT
   ,[Facet] VARCHAR(32)
);

INSERT INTO @table1 ([MANDT], [DOKNR], [LFDNR])
VALUES (1, '0020999956', NULL)
      ,(1, '0020999958', NULL)
      ,(1, '0020999960', 2)
      ,(1, '0020999960', 3)
      ,(1, '0020999960', NULL)
      ,(1, '0020999962',NULL)

INSERT INTO @table2 ([DataID], [Facet])
VALUES (42101976, '0020999956')
      ,(42100240, '0020999958')
      ,(65688960, '0020999960')
      ,(65694287, '0020999960')
      ,(65697507, '0020999960')
      ,(42113401, '0020999962');

WITH DataSource ([DataID], [DOKNR], [LFDNR]) AS
(
    SELECT *
         ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Facet] ORDER BY [DataID])
    FROM @table2
)
UPDATE @table1
SET [DataID] = DS.[DataID]
FROM @table1 T
INNER JOIN DataSource DS
    ON T.[DOKNR] = DS.[DOKNR]
    AND ISNULL(T.[LFDNR], 1) = DS.[LFDNR];

SELECT *
FROM @table1;
```

[image]